# Text does not want to wrap when I shrink down the window from desktop to mobile banner

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, media-queries

I am trying to have the text in my project fit and justify accordingly when the dimensions of the screen smaller. So the text does not wrap for some reason even if I have it in the code.

I tried to input all the html classes I need to have the changes applied to in teh media query and have it be applied when the width of the screen goes lower but it does not work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito+Sans:ital,opsz,wght@0,6..12,200..1000;1,6..12,200..1000&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="globals.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="banner">
      <div class="text">
        <img class="vector" id="vctr" src="Imagery/vector--2nd.png" />
        <div class="frame">
          <div class="title-with-icon">
            <img
              id="img--green--thunder"
              class="bolt-lightning"
              src="Imagery/green--thunder.png"
              style="width: 21px; height: 28px; margin-left: 16.5px"
            />
            <p class="text-wrapper">10% Отстъпка за първата ви поръчка</p>
          </div>
          <p class="div">
            Get a complimentary 10% discount on your car insurance. Become a
            Trusti member and take advantage of this temporary offer!
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="text-button">
          <button class="CTA">Научи повече</button>
          <div class="icon" style="bottom: 24px">
            <img src="Imagery/Icon.png" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="mediaElements">
        <img class="star" src="Imagery/entire--star.png" />
        <img class="image" src="Imagery/group--component.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
.banner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: var(--tokens-spacing-horizontal-horizontal-space-lg);
  background-color: var(--neutralshade-400-white);
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #009147;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 162px;
  max-width: 1204px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  justify-content: space-between; /*bzh addition*/
  flex-wrap: wrap; /*bzh addition*/
}

.banner .mediaElements {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 452px;
  height: 162px;
}

#img--green--thunder {
  margin-left: 16.5px;
  margin-top: 24px;
}

#vctr {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 636px;
  height: 162px;
  left: 99.5px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.banner .star {
  position: absolute;
  width: 383px;
  height: 383px;
  top: -90px;
  left: 38px;
}

.banner .title-with-icon {
  display: flex;
}

.banner .text {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 16px;
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.banner .frame {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  position: relative;
  align-self: stretch;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.banner .text-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  align-self: stretch;
  margin-top: -1px;
  font-family: "Nunito Sans";
  font-weight: var(--desktop-h4-bold-font-weight);
  color: var(--neutralshade-900-text);
  letter-spacing: var(--desktop-h4-bold-letter-spacing);
  line-height: var(--desktop-h4-bold-line-height);
  left: 10.5px;
  top: 24px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 32px;
}

.banner .div {
  position: relative;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: wrap;
  width: 513px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-weight: var(--global-body-small-font-weight);
  color: var(--neutralshade-900-text);
  font-size: var(--global-body-small-font-size);
  letter-spacing: var(--global-body-small-letter-spacing);
  line-height: var(--global-body-small-line-height);
  font-style: var(--global-body-small-font-style);
  left: 48px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 21px;
  bottom: 16px;
}

.banner .text-button {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: var(--collection-1-0-5-rem-duplicate);
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.banner .CTA {
  all: unset;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
  margin-top: -1px;
  font-family: var(--global-label-font-family);
  font-weight: var(--global-label-font-weight);
  color: var(--shadesshade-900-black);
  font-size: var(--global-label-font-size);
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: var(--global-label-letter-spacing);
  line-height: var(--global-label-line-height);
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-style: var(--global-label-font-style);
  left: 48px;
  bottom: 24px;
}

.banner .icon {
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: var(--orangeorange-800-primary);
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
  left: 54px;
}

.banner .image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 362px;
  height: 162px;
  top: 0;
  left: 90px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) and (min-width: 327px) {
  .banner {
    min-width: auto;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .banner.text {
    justify-content: justify;
    text-align: left;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
  }
  #vctr {
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

Comment: `flex-direction: wrap;` is probably the problem. `wrap` is not a direction.